# Javascript if select box is disabled no error

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

currently im working with a form that on submit uses javascript to validate all of the forms input fields and throws errors if a field is incomplete. I have an option though, that when checked will disabled a few of the inputs, and im looking to `stop the errors from being thrown if the textbox is disabled.`

relevant code includes:

html:

```
                <select name="os" id="os">
                    <option>-Select-</option> 
                    <option value="A">Android</option> 
                    <option value="I">iOS</option>
                     <option value="W">Windows Mobile</option> 
                 </select> <font color="#CC0000">*</font>
```

js

```
if (document.FrontPage_Form1.Action[0].checked==true) 
    {
        var dropvalue = document.getElementById("os");
        var dropText = dropvalue.options[dropvalue.selectedIndex].text;


            if (dropText=="-Select-") && (dropvalue.disabled=false)
            {
                document.getElementById("OS_Msg").style.display='';
                document.getElementById("OS_Err").style.display='';

                valid==false;
            }

    }
```

jQuery disable

```
<p><input type="checkbox" name="noPhone" id="noPhone">: My Device does not have a phone number.</p>

<script type="text/javascript">

            $("#noPhone").click(onCheckChange).change(onCheckChange);

                        function onCheckChange() {
                          if ($("#noPhone").is(':checked'))
                          {
                            $("select.focusDrop").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                            $(":text").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            $("select.focusDrop").removeAttr('disabled');
                            $(":text").removeAttr('disabled');
                          } 
                        }

            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from missing a set of parenthesis wrapping around `(dropText=="-Select-") && (dropvalue.disabled=false)`, you're setting a value instead of comparing it with

```
dropvalue.disabled=false
```

It should be

```
dropvalue.disabled==false
```

And as pointed out by Guffa, `valid==false;` should be `valid=false;`

Comment: Also, `valid==false;` should be `valid=false;`. (Just too small to make it into an answer by itself.)

Comment: looks like the previous developer had the same ID used in another spot. Thanks for the extra set of eyes guys!